# Dynamically allocated std::vector seems to have memory leak

Tags: c++, stl, memory-leaks, vector

Thanks to everybody and After checking again in the whole project the real problem was missing of virtual destractor.... that cause the memory leak...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

class VecContainerParent
{
public:
    VecContainerParent(){};
```

**Without this line:**

```
    virtual ~VecContainerParent(){};
```

**it cause the memory leak**

```
};

class VecContainerChild : public VecContainerParent
{
public:
    VecContainerChild(){};

    //virtual ~VecContainerChild(){};
private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};

////////// WITH MEMORY LEAK ///////////////


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VecContainerParent *a;
    while(true)
    {
        a = new VecContainerChild();
        delete a;
    }
}
```

///// Original Post //////////
*I have a problem of memory leak, when using vector inside of class, and then use this object with new & delete.
It seem that the vector inside the class don't free memory.
For testing this I see in the task-manager that the memory of the process increase dramatically.*

Please see the example below:

```
class VecContainer
{
public:
       VecContainer(){};
private:
       std::vector<int> vec;
}
```

1. With memory leak:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       VecContainer *a;
       while(true)
       {
           a = new VecContainer();
           delete a;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Good (because is not using ptr):

   ```
   int main()
   {
       while(true)
       {
           VecContainer a;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: There is no memory leak in either code snippet.

Comment: ... unless you replaced the default `operator new` and/or `operator delete` with defective versions.

Comment: Can you please post some evidence that this is leaking memory? There's no obvious leak going on here.

Comment: Also, if the memory manager doesn't reuse the same memory each time through the loop in case 1, it could *look* like it's "leaking" memory because more and more physical RAM would be assigned to the process' virtual address space, so a tool like `top` would show increased memory usage. It would just be a phantom, though; as soon as something else needed it, it would get reclaimed.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: Yes, the `()` indicates that it's to be value-initialised. In the case of a class with a user-declared default constructor, it makes no difference; in the case of POD types, it means they are zero-initialised rather than left uninitialised.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: There's a leak in the second, since the automatic vector is in a block that will never exit normally.

Comment: Ah, right. I was thinking of the declaration case, where `VecContainer a;` means `a` is a `VecContainer` allocated on the stack while `VecContainer a();` is declaring a function returning a `VecContainer`.

Comment: "i see in the task-manger that the memory of the process increase dramatically" - Are you sure it's not CPU usage that's increasing?

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Does that even count? If the program is, say, aborted, there will exist at most one `VecContainer` worth of storage to be cleaned up by the OS. Not really a leak as it is quite bounded. This, of course, assumes that `VecContainer::~VecContainer()` does not leak.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: No, it doesn't really count; I was just being pedantic. And `~VecContainer` can't leak anything, since it just calls `~vector`  - which is presumably fine, otherwise snippet 2 would have an unbounded leak.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `delete` will release memory back to the operating system; small allocations are typically kept for reuse in a heap. But I would certainly expect snippet 1 to only allocate a small amount of memory and then reuse it; if the usage does keep increasing, then there's something fishy happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's typical. When you

```
   a = new VecContainerChild();
    delete a;
```

delete an object through a pointer to its base class subobject, you invoke undefined behaviour *unless* the base class has a virtual destructor. Basically, the child's destructor isn't run in this case.

[This might be a question to study further.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294927/51831)