# C++ Unexpected error when deleting objects

Tags: c++, memory-management

I write an interpreter, in which each keyword, syntax notation or operator has the base class of `Token`.

```
class Token {
    private:
        static std::vector<Token *> registered;

        size_t id;

        std::string name;
        std::string symbol;

    public:
        Token(const std::string& Name, const std::string& Symbol);
        Token::~Token();

        Token(const Token& rhs) = delete;
        Token& operator =(const Token& rhs) = delete;

        /* ... */

        static void DeleteRegistered();
};
```

The **constructor**:

```
Token::Token(const std::string& Name, const std::string& Symbol)
                : name(Name), symbol(Symbol) {
    Token::registered.push_back(this);
    this->id = Token::registered.size();
}
```

The **destructor**:

```
Token::~Token() {
    // Removes 'this' from Token::registered
    Token::registered.erase(std::remove(Token::registered.begin(), Token::registered.end(), this), Token::registered.end());
}
```

**DeleteRegistered**:

```
void Token::DeleteRegistered() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Token::registered.size(); ++i) {
        delete Token::registered[i];
    }
}
```

In my code, many different classes store containers of pointers to sub-classes which eventually derive from Token.

In order to avoid deleting objects twice or more, I store references to all of the allocated instances, and have a static method which will delete them all.

The method `DeleteRegistered` is called after all operations are done executing.

Now, to my problem:

When I call `Token::DeleteRegistered` (which happens a few lines before the program exits, it fails and in debug shows the following:

```
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

[image: The memory, just one line before the programs crashes]

Since all of the `Token` instances don't really have a defined scope, I came up with this design, which to me currently seems OK.

What can cause this error?

**EDIT:**
The destructor was a late addition of mine, commenting it out still shows the error above. The `delete` fails to delete even the first item in the container.

**2ND EDIT:**
An example of how I use `Token`:

```
this->parser.Operators.Add(new RefBinaryOperator(
    "Assignment", "=", 14, RefBinaryOperator::Assign
));
```

Note: RefBinaryOperator is a sub-class of `Token` (Not direct), which eventually calls `Token`'s constructor.

So for instance, I pull pointers to `Token`s from the `Operators` container, and assign them to other structures. When everything is done, I call `DeleteRegistered`.

**FINAL EDIT:**

I got it working by declaring the Token destructor as `virtual`:

[Does delete work with pointers to base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/does-delete-work-with-pointers-to-base-class)

Comment: Since each token will be registered/unregistered in that list during the `Token` lifetime you might end up deleting tokens defined on the Stack or inside another class. Also , how to you create the tokens ?

Comment: @Raxvan All tokens are dynamically allocated, sorry for not pointing that out. And if there were, the `Token` destructor would be called, and delete its reference from the container, before calling `DeleteRegistered`.

Comment: Hm, the `Token::DeleteRegistered()` won't delete most of the objects, but I don't see how that would cause a crash. Are you perhaps using the `id` member for anything? Once you delete an object, the `id`s stop matching and you will be getting multiple instances with same id...

Comment: I don't know whether it's causing your problem, but you'll need a virtual destructor. There's also no way to ensure that all instances are created with `new`; how are you making sure all of them are deletable?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I don't see any inhe... oh, you are right, it is not present in the example, but it is described in the text! Yes, that'll be the thing. Missing virtual destructors _will_ make things behave funky.

Comment: `In order to avoid deleting objects twice or more, I store references to all of the allocated instances,` Maybe you should invest in using a smart pointer such as std::shared_ptr instead of trying to keep track of number of instances.  Using shared_ptr, once remove() does its job, that's it.  You don't need that static member array.

Comment: Have you checked that what you posted actually demonstrates the problem? I am almost certain it does not, which obviously makes it difficult to point the problem out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Or a shared container like `boost::shared_container`. But what I find confusing is that there is deletion happening without a new. Can you `delete` stack allocated objects? I've never tried it.

Comment: @Dennis: "Can you delete stack allocated objects?" - No, you can't. This design requires everything to be created with `new`; which is one possible cause of failure.

Comment: When `Operators` is deleted are the tokens also destroyed? This could be a source of duplicate deletion.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks. Instinctively I thought it might be a problem, but never tried giving the address of a stack object to `delete`.

Comment: Well, `Operators` does not have a destructor. No `Token`s are deleted when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Tyymo - As per my earlier comment regarding the `delete` operator, are you allocating every `Token` using `new`??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening is that in `Token::~Token()` you are calling `erase` from the `registered` vector which is invalidating the indices used in the for loop where you noticed the problem. You need to remember that once you call `erase` on that vector, the for loop indices need to be adjusted properly. If you keep your current destructor the following could work in `DeleteRegistered`:

```
void DeleteRegistered() {
  while(!Token::registered.empty())
    delete *Token::registered.begin();
}
```

Also, since you have many classes which extend off of `Token`, `~Token()` should become virtual so that the destruction for the base class will be properly handled.

Comment: The iteration was with indices, not iterators, so the only thing it did was it failed to delete half of the objects. But I don't see how it could have caused a crash.

Comment: Down-vote, because "delete v[i]" actually doesn't change the vector size.

Comment: `while(not Token::registered.empty()) delete Token::registered.front();` is also possible. I think it would be better though to delete from the end (because of the `remove`).

Comment: I am afraid that with your suggestion, the error still shows up.

Comment: @fasked: But the destructor (called by the delete expression) does.

Comment: @pippin1289 i would change `for` to `while(Token::registered.size())`

Comment: @fasked you are incorrect in this case, because the Token destructor changes the size of the vector

Comment: Of course. This just ensures everything is deleted, but does not address bad deletes. @MikeSeymour hints the correct answer in the comment.

Comment: I will adjust my answer to also include what @MikeSeymour hinted at.

Comment: @pippin For testing- I commented out the destructor. Still, The program crashes as soon as I try to delete the first object.

Comment: In the code you have shown, we are assuming that the Tokens are dynamically instantiated. If they are statically instantiated then they have previously been deleted, and you cannot delete the same memory twice.

Comment: No `Token`s are statically instantiated.

Comment: @Tyymo - I think you need to post a simple main() function to show how you're using this Token class and usage that causes the issue.  Right now, it's confusing as to where those Token pointers come from, whether they are dynamically allocated, etc...

Comment: ok.  I see your edit.  Seriously, your issue here would be greatly reduced, if not totally disappear if you used a shared_ptr or shared_container.

Comment: @Tyymo - Your description in your edit is a use case for shared_ptr. `So for instance, I pull pointers to Tokens from the Operators container, and assign them to other structures. When everything is done, I call DeleteRegistered`.  If you used a shared_ptr, there is no need for the DeleteRegistered function.  The shared_ptr or similar construct will do all of this work that you're trying to do "by hand" now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When will `shared_ptr` delete the allocated object?

Comment: @Tyymo - when the reference count for the pointer goes to 0. So basically, you can assign that shared_ptr to your heart's content to any array any time. It is when the instance is no longer needed, the reference count for the shared_ptr goes down by 1. As soon as there is no one referencing that pointer anymore, then the memory is finally deleted due to a 0 reference count.

Comment: @Tymmo - Here is a link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

If you need an example using something looking like your code, I can provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Token::DeleteRegistered() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Token::registered.size(); ++i) {
        delete Token::registered[i];
    }
}
```

The above will not do what you want. It's going to remove the first (0th) element from `registered`. What was the second element now becomes the first (0th element), but now `i` will be 1. Your loop will remove only every other element from `Token::registered`. It leaks.

One way to handle this: Keep removing either the first or last element while the vector is not empty. I'd suggest deleting the last element because that's more consistent with how vectors work. Deleting the first element until the vector is empty involves rebuilding the vector each step.

```
void Token::DeleteRegistered() {
    while (! Token::registered.empty()) {
        delete Token::registered.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: `remove` isn't going to modify `registered` (at least, not in any way that invalidates iterators), so it doesn't matter which order the arguments of `erase` are evaluated in.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I stand corrected. I'm deleting (and erasing!) the first part of my answer. The problem is in `DeleteRegistered`, not `Token::~Token`.

Comment: @DavidHammen Trying out your solution, it does manage to delete the first two `Token`'s, but crashes afterwards.

Comment: @Tyymo - As PaulMcKenzie suggested a couple of minutes ago in his comment to your question, you should show us a minimal working example.

Comment: Despite the fact that your suggestion did not work, it led me to find the true problem with my code. Thanks