# The Virtual Destructor in C++

Tags: c++

I really have gone through the existing questions and I still really need this question answered to really know if I understood this right.

Usually, the only time we define our own destructor is when something is dynamically allocated on memory.

However, we still need to implement our own destructor (even if there is nothing dynamically allocated on the heap) just for sake of naming it virtual (and it can just be pure virtual if there is nothing allocated on heap) when we are using the base class addresses (pointers/references) to access the objects of the derived classes. Is this (my deduction) unconditionally correct?

Because if there is:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
```

Now to delete p, i.e. free memory, we MUST have the destructor declared as virtual and do:

```
delete p;
```

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

> `Base* p = new Derived;`
>
> Now to delete p, i.e. free memory, we MUST have the destructor declared as virtual and do:
>
> `delete p;`
>
> Correct?

**Yes**

As the answer to this question ([Does delete work with pointers to base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/does-delete-work-with-pointers-to-base-class) also states.

> Yes, it will work, if and only if the base class destructor is virtual

### C++ 11

If the destructor's implementation is trivial you can just do

```
virtual ~Base() = default;
```

Furthermore the derived types should make use of `override`.

```
virtual ~Derived() override = default;
^^^1^^^            ^^^2^^^^
// 1: Optional because the base destructor is virtual
// 2: The compiler will verify the base destructor is virtual
```

Comment: Thank you James. You're a star. BTW, how is `= default` different from the pure virtual `= 0` ?

Comment: @BloodBrother `= 0` doesn't provide an implementation whereas `= default` explicitly tells the compilers to auto generate the implementation.

Comment: @BloodBrother if the answer is satisfactory, it is a good idea to accept it. If you keep asking questions without accepting answers, soon you won't get any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is best to assume there will be subclasses that have destructors that need to be run, so the virtual destructor needs to exist in `Base`. Also, even in scenarios where you don't have code in any destructors, other things are expected to happen on destruction.

```
class Derived : public Base {
    MyMember m;
}
```

With no virtual destructor on `Base`, the destructor of `m` will never be called when you delete polymorphically (deleting it as a `Base*`).

If you plan to allow subclassing of `Base` for arbitrary subclasses, you need `Base` to have a virtual destructor in order to safely delete these subclasses.

It is not recommended to consider a nonvirtual destructor for `Base` because you would need to guarantee that all subclasses not only have no destructor, but also that they all have *no members with destructors*... that means no stl containers or anything else in the object. It's very easy for such strange requirements to be missed by other developers, so you should just have a virtual destructor in `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make the destructor of the base class virtual. Derived classes can define the destructor explicitly or use the implicit one defined by the constructor.

```
struct Base
{
   virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
   // Explicitly defined destructor.
   // Use of virtual is optional.
   ~Derived () {}
   std::vector<std::string>> data;
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
   // Use the compiler defined destructor
   std::vector<int>> data;
};
```

Usage:

```
Base* p = new Derived1;
...
delete p;   // OK

p = new Derived2;
...
delete p;   // OK
```