# Can we perform deleting object through a pointer to one of its base classes?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Does it cause UB if we define a virtual destructor? For intance:

```
struct A{ virtual ~A(){ } };

struct B : A { };

A *a = new B;


int main()
{
    delete a; //UB?
}
```

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63a6df49827e20ea)

Comment: Perfectly OK. This is what polymorphism is about. (But indeed, make sure that destructor is virtual.)

Comment: @AlexD Why the virtulality of the destructor is importnt here? I know if we didn't ever declare the destructor we would get UB.

Comment: see [Does delete work with pointers to base class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/294927/1708801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Does it cause UB if we define a virtual destructor?"*

No that's just fine as the destructor was declared `virtual`. Stepping up the `vtable` and calling `~B` first will be handled by `delete`.

Comment: But what actually the virtual destructor gives us which non-virtual doesn't?

Comment: @St.Antario _"But what actually the virtual destructor gives us ..."_ It ensures you to have a `vtable`, that enables that behavior of `delete`.

Comment: We would have the vtable if we declared any other function virtual, not a destructor. That also makes the class polymorphic.

Comment: @St.Antario Well, still that mechanism (`vtable`) only works for functions found in it. If you don't declare the destructor `virtual`, any overrides can't be resolved from the `vtable`.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine *precisely because* the destructor is `virtual` — otherwise it would have been UB.

In other words, if you want to delete objects of derived type, through  pointers of base type, then the destructor of base class **must be** `virtual`, else it would be UB. That ensures that the *correct* destructor (i.e the destructor of derived) is invoked — that is called runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Its fine, so long as the destructor is `virtual`.

If the destuctor is not, it will not know to delete the members of the subclass.