# C++ polymorphic class pointer in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, polymorphism

Let's say I have the following code which, in short, has:

- a `BaseClass` with a pointer to a `PointerClass`
- a `ChildClass` that inherits from `BaseClass`
- a `HolderClass` that has an `std::vector` of `ChildClass`s and an `std::vector` of `BaseClass*`s:

The entire code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

class PointerClass {
public:
    int num;
    double num2;
    PointerClass() {
        srand(time(NULL));
        num = rand() % 100;
        num2 = rand() % 100 / 2.0;
    }
};


class BaseClass {
public:
    PointerClass *pointerClass;
};


class ChildClass: public BaseClass {
public:
    ChildClass() {
        pointerClass = new PointerClass();
    }
};


class HolderClass {
public:
    std::vector<BaseClass*> basePointerVec;
    std::vector<ChildClass> childVec;

    HolderClass() {

    }

    void addParentClass() {
        ChildClass childClass = ChildClass();

        childVec.push_back(childClass);
        basePointerVec.push_back(&childClass);
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    HolderClass holderClass = HolderClass();

    for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
        holderClass.addParentClass();
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < holderClass.basePointerVec.size(); count++) {
        delete holderClass.basePointerVec[count]->pointerClass;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, after adding a pointer to the `ChildClass` into the `std::vector<BaseClass*> basePointerVec` and the actual `ChildClass` into the `std::vector<ChildClass> childVec` in the `addParentClass()` method in `HolderClass`, the data in `basePointerVec` and`childVec` are completely different.

Furthermore, when I try to free the `PointerClass`es from the `childVec`, everything works fine. But when I try to free them from the `basePointerVec` instead, I get an error telling my I'm trying to free a pointer I have not allocated memory for.

And sure enough, when I use breakpoints to inspect everything, I find some funky behavior.  It seems that every time I call `ChildClass childClass = ChildClass();` in `addParentClass()`, every pointer in `basePointerVec` gets changed to point to the newly created `ChildClass`'s `BaseClass`.

The point of me doing this in my actual program is to take advantage of polymorphism and have multiple classes inherit from `BaseClass`.

So my question is, why is every pointer in the vector being changed to point to the newly created class and how can I fix it?

P.S. sorry for the length of this question, it's as short as I could possibly make it

Comment: virtual destructor in base class!!

Comment: You seriously don't want to do it this way. Even if you straightened out your object creation and addressing and used `basePointerVec.push_back(&childVec.back());` you're still in a world of hurt as soon as `childVec` expands and allocates a different memory bed for the expanded space. All the pointers in your `basePointerVec` will be invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    childVec.push_back(childClass);
```

The push_back method of the class vector copies the object. So the added object is not the same as childClass in this case.

You can't delete the pointers from basePointerVec because they were not allocated with new but they were allocated locally and **they are deleted at the end of addParentClass**. So, the code of addParent is wrong because the pointer you push in the vector is no longer valid after the end of the method and may cause segmentation faults(in best case). Here is a suggestion of improvement:

```
void addParentClass() {
    ChildClass* childClass = new ChildClass();

    childVec.push_back(*childClass);
    basePointerVec.push_back(childClass);
}
```

The memory is now allocated dynamically, you should make sure to free these pointers with delete.

EDIT:

```
void addParentClass() {
    childVec.push_back(ChildClass());
    basePointerVec.push_back(&childVec.back());
}
```

And if you are using C++11:

```
void addParentClass() {
    childVec.emplace_back();
    basePointerVec.push_back(&childVec.back());
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't get what the OP wants. He wants the items within the `childVec` vector to be addressed by pointers in `basePointerVec`. The code you posted here will create *two* `ChildClass` instances per invoke; one pushed by copy-construction into `childVec`, the other pointed to by `basePoniterVec`.

Comment: I edited the post. I forgot this point in my answer. By the way what does OP mean?

Comment: @WhozCraig I believe the original solution will work for me.  As long as the data in each of the vectors is the same, I don't need the items in `childVec` to point to `basePointerVec`.  And as you mentioned in your comment above doing that would be very wrong.  I will also look into `shared_ptr` as @AmiTavory suggested.  And while every answer on here is correct, I will mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: I should note that in order to use the original solution, one must give `BaseClass` a virtual destructor `virtual ~BaseClass {};` so that one can call `delete basePointerVec[number]`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294927/does-delete-work-with-pointers-to-base-class) post for details.

Comment: @glazed4444 " I don't need the items in childVec to point to basePointerVec" - actually the way your original post showed, it would be the other way around. `childVec` doesn't "point" to anything; it's housing the actual objects. And what I said is true: if a resize of that vector happens and a new memory bed is used, the base pointer vector will be filled with *dangling* pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already addressed the specific problem in your code. Here are two general points about your program above that will help you IMHO avoid all sorts of problems in the future:

1. When you define a class, esp. one which can be subclassed, always make the dtor `public virtual` except if you have a specific reason not too.
2. Always store resources in classes with the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle:

   - Except for a good reason, you should never have a naked member pointer. Use a [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) member instead.
   - Except for a good reason, you should never have a `vector` of naked pointers. Again use a vector of shared pointers.

---

Using this, hopefully, you won't need to track in your head what got destroyed when before something was copied to whatever, etc. It will make it harder to mix up heap objects and stack objects.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
void addParentClass() {
    ChildClass childClass = ChildClass();

    childVec.push_back(childClass);
    basePointerVec.push_back(&childClass);
}
```

Your objects are not allocated on the heap. They are values and in `basePointerVec` you put their addresses (which don't make sense anyway after `addParentClass()` returns). Don't try to delete those, that will crash your program. They will be automatically deleted when `childVec` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

When `addParentClass` returns, the `childClass` object is destroyed. Therefore, the pointer to that object, that you put into `basePointerVec` cannot be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local variable that is destroyed as soon `addParentClass` goes out of scope. Also see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673998/what-is-difference-between-instantiating-an-object-using-new-vs-without) which explains what happens when you don't use `new`. So the vector of `BaseClass` pointers are pointing to an object that is destroyed, and the `childVec` vector of objects are creating new copies when you use `push_back`, from [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> The new element is initialized as a copy of value.

This is why the two vectors are pointing to different objects. You could create a destructor for the classes and add debugging prints to the destructor and the constructor to see when the objects are created/destroyed, this should give you a better idea of what is happening in what order.